# Customise node label and add title to Sankey diagram

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-google-charts

I would like to add title to each level data of Sankey chart (act as column label) and each data label is labelling with count (which act like legend). One more, are we able to position the first level label to be outside of the bar?
The expected result as my description is as below.

[Expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cTLJ.png)